# Formula in Excel that can create special prices that are higher than the cost price and lower than the msrp price?

Tags: excel, opencart, formula, discount

So I'm using OpenCart and I have about 6000 products and adding. I don't think that really matters, but just in case. I was wondering if there is a formula in Excel that I can use to create special prices that are higher than the cost price and lower than the msrp price?
My columns are SKU Name Cost MSRP

Can anyone help me out? 
Much appreciation!

Comment: prices should be random? if yes, something like this: `=RANDBETWEEN(C1,D1)` (generates rand values >= COST and <=MSRP). or `=RANDBETWEEN(1.001*C1,0.9999*D1)` (generates rand values > COST and <MSRP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your pricing is based on a "mark-up" factor.

If **C1** contains the cost and **D1** contains the MSRP, then in **E1** enter:

```
=IF(1.03*C1>D1,D1,1.03*C1)
```

where the 1.03 is your mark-up factor (modify this to meet your needs)..This says that if the marked-up price exceeds MSRP, use MSRP.  Otherwise use the marked-up price.